# What does tabs[0] mean in browser extensions?

Tags: javascript, browser, firefox-addon

In the Firefox example of browser extensions, the popup script sends a message to the content script using the following:

```
browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {

command: "beastify", beastURL: url }
```

Looking through the MDN documentation doesn't give a clear cut answer as to what tabs really is. It seems like its an array containing all the tab objects in the browser. But how do I know what tabs[0] is? and what about the rest of the array?

Is using tabs[0] equivalent to finding the current active tab?

Comment: Got a link to the documentation that shows this? I'll bet it's explained somewhere on that site.

Comment: tabs is an array that would have been declared somewhere. Find the line where it is declared, and you'll see what function call returned it. It's most probably an array of tabs returned from a call to a method like browser.tabs.query

Answer (score 1):

This is from Firefox [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension)

```
browser.tabs
  .query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
  .then(beastify)

....

function beastify(tabs) {
  browser.tabs.insertCSS({ code: hidePage }).then(() => {
    let url = beastNameToURL(e.target.textContent);
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
      command: "beastify",
      beastURL: url
    });
  });
}
```

As you can see the `beastify` function is called with list (array) of tabs from `browser.tabs.query()`

Because only one tab in the same window can be active, it's save to say that the list will contain only single item, hens we can safely use `tabs[0]` to access first and only item in the array.

Comment: What if I have multiple windows open? Each window would have one active tab, so how would things change in that scenario?

Comment: Just take a look at the filter used in the query: `{ active: true, currentWindow: true }`. You can't have more than one focused window/tab at a time